# Is every abelian Lie algebra a direct sum of $1$-dimensional ideals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, ideals

First, I asked myself if it is true that every abelian algebra has only $1$-dimensional ideals: my impression is that it is false, but I can't seem to find a counterexample. In fact, I can only come up with examples of abelian Lie algebras of dimension 1. Any hints?

Comment: Any vector space becomes an abelian Lie algebra by setting the bracket to zero. Every subspace is again an abelian Lie algebra.

Comment: Every subspace is also an ideal in @Joppy's example.

Comment: Oh right. So maybe in the context of abelian Lie algebras it is true that every subalgebra is an ideal? In fact, if $L$ is an abelian Lie algebra and $H$ is a subalgebra, if $x \in H$ and $y \in L -H$ , than $[x,y] = 0 \in H$. In that case it would be easy to conclude that an abelian Lie algebra does not have only 1-dimensional ideals. Is it correct?